# In Banshee, how can I export a simple list of all the music in my library?

Tags: backup, music, libraries, banshee

I'd like to have a sort of doomsday backup, so that even if I somehow lose everything, I at least know what I need to replace. Tips for other music players welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Banshee you can create a smart playlist which contains all the music in your library (for example with the condition: file size more than 0 bytes) then right click on the playlist, choose export playlist, and you can save the playlist in `.m3u` format.

Answer (score 2):

See: /home/YOUR USERNAME/.config/banshee/ -> There you'll find the database all titles are saved in (included ratings, etc). It's recommended to save the whole dir, because there are plugins/settings as well.

Comment: This should be accepted answer since it provides a comprehensive backup instead of a single m3u playlist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this temporary solution, which only works on libraries that are well-organized on the file/folder level:

```
ls library/*/* >> fulllist
```

Where each directory under `library` is structured as `artist/album/song`.

This will store a list of ALBUMS (not individual songs) in `fulllist`. If you want songs, change `library/*/*` to `library/*/*/*` You may have to tweak this depending on how your library is structured. Mine is `library/format/artist/album/song`.